# Query a SQL table with string list of column names

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have two questions
1. I have a list of string which is the column names. How can i use it in the SQL query?
2. Is the method prone to SQL injection?

This is what i have right now,

```
List<string> Columnnames = new List<string>();

 cmd = new SqlCommand("Select "+Columnnames+" from test");
```

Comment: Where do the column names come from? User input? And why do you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: the only way to truly prevent SQL injection is having mostly everything as View or store procedure in SQL itself with very good triggers and validation.

Comment: yes it is user input from a listbox with all column names.

Comment: @Franck that is simply incorrect; sorry, but it is. Parameterized sql - completely separate to views, sprocs, etc - does not risk sql injection

Comment: @user3272054 never ever trust the UI ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell that's what i said. store proc is the way to prevent injection. sending standard TSQL from application to server is not.

Comment: @Franck and again, you are entirely incorrect. Standard TSQL **that uses parameters** is entirely safe. This does not involve stored procedures in any way. "store proc is the way to prevent injection" is not just incorrect; it is actively unhelpful, IMO.

Comment: @MarcGravell Here we got injected TSQL tests with our linux server guy who had some application that seems easy to use that read in and out from 2 point and was able to specifically detect SQL call and switch query as he wanted to. Sorry but i call that injection. Then we started switching to store proc and he could still change it but TSQL is blocked on our servers now and only SP are permitted so changing it is useless.

Comment: @Franck whether that is "injection" depends on where they are manipulating the query; if they are changing the stream between your app-server and the db-server, then no: that is a MITM attack - and can be prevented by secure internal network transports inside your DMZ - readily available. That same MITM attack - without secure transports - still leaves you vulnerable even if you use sprocs (it requires a compromised internal network, though). If he was simply sending values to your UI via a tool like "havij", then: your SQL was simply not correctly parameterized.

Comment: @MarcGravell The guy tell me it was called sniffing or something like that. He says it read network packets between 2 or more IP and other software can be used to interpret what it is and SQL is only 1 of them. it's probably that thing you are talking about. Me i call injection as soon as my sql log file don't have the same thing as what the application sends.

Comment: @Franck yes, that is a MITM attack. It is completely separate to "injection", and should not be confused with it. You are **still vulnerable to that attack**: using a sproc doesn't prevent a MITM from changing the parameters... for example, changing the "to" account number in a balance transfer to be their own. You haven't actually solved the problem: if you wanted to do that, there is a readily available, very well supported fix: *use a secure transport between the app-server and the db-server*. But again: that is not SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

Question 1 - change your code to something like:

```
List<string> Columnnames = new List<string>();

// Code that populates Columnnames here

cmd = new SqlCommand("Select " + string.Join(",", Columnnames) + " from test");
```

Question 2 - depends on how you are populating `Columnnames`. If this is being populated from input over the web then yes.

Comment: Thanks that works. The Columnnames is populated over the user input from a listbox with all column name. Is there still a chance for SQL Injection?

Comment: @user3272054 what is the UI here? web? winform? WPF? If the answer is "web", then the answer is "yes, absolutely; trivially easy". If the answer is "winform"  / "WPF", then "kinda probably yes, but they'd have to really work hard at it, and it would be easier to just go direct to your sql server, since they probably have access"

Comment: @user3272054 if it is winforms, and you are doing database access code, then presumably your user *already has access to the database server*. Asking about SQL injection is almost moot (except for simple things like fixing apostrophe problems) - they can just *waltz into the database server*

Answer (score 1):

If the column names are coming from an outside source, then yes, you would have to concatenate them into the string. You should ideally use `[`/`]`, but that just allows for column names with spaces etc - it doesn't change anything about SQL injection, and yes: allowing column names to be specified by a user would be a SQL injection risk, unless you white-list them first. So perhaps:

```
if(Columnnames.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException(
    "You need to specify at least one column");

var sql = new StringBuilder("select ");
bool first = true;
foreach(var name in Columnnames) {
    if(!IsKnownColumnName(name)) { // <=== very important test
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid column name: " + name);
    }
    sql.Append(first ? "[" : ",[").Append(name).Append("]");
    first = false;
}
sql.Append(" from test");
...
cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert list of `Columnnames` to comma separated column values. Like this:

```
string columns = Columnnames.Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y);
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select "+columns+" from test");
```

This method is prone to sql injection as someone can easily send column name like `column ;drop database yourDB` so its a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

First check if Columnames haves any value.
Second make a function to create something like dus columna, columnb

SqlCommend should look like this select columna , columb from test;

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the column names to the query so that each column name is separated with a comma from the next, e.g. (pseudo)

```
define sql = "SELECT "

for columnName in columnNames:
    concatenate sql,columnName

    if columnName is not last:
        concatenate sql,","
    end if
end for

concatenate sql," FROM test"
```

Vulnerability depends on the source of the column names. If you have internal immutable list(s) of column names, then there's no risk but if they somehow originate from an external source, such as a user using the application, then it certainly is prone to SQL-injection.